# Accessing object properties from object itself

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm having a little trouble learning object-oriented Javascript. I have two classes called `Cosmos` and `Background`, `Cosmos` looks like this:

```
// js/Cosmos.js
function Cosmos() {
    this.background = new Background();

    // Fire game loop
    this.ticker = setInterval(this.tick, 1000 / 60);
}

// Main game loop
Cosmos.prototype.tick = function() {
    console.log(this.background);
}
```

When the main game loop ticks, I get `undefined` in console. I don't quite understand this because `this.background` is a property of the `Cosmos` class, so it should be accessible by the methods defined in the `Cosmos` class, no?

If I go back to my `index.html` page's script tag and change it to this:

```
// Lift off
var cosmos = new Cosmos();
console.log(cosmos.background);
```

it works and the `Background` object gets logged to the console. Can anyone offer an explanation and tell me how I can access the properties of `Cosmos` from within `Cosmos.tick`?

Edit: Turns out the problem is something to do with `setInterval()`, because if I do this the proper object is logged to console:

```
function Cosmos() {
    this.background = new Background();

    // Fire game loop
    //this.ticker = setInterval(this.tick, 1000 / 60);
    this.tick();
}

// Main game loop
Cosmos.prototype.tick = function() {
    console.log(this.background);
}
```

still don't know the best way around it, though.

Comment: None of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]Accessing+object+properties+from+object+itself) was useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function is called from `setInterval`, `this` will not be bound to the object anymore.

This is a quick fix to your problem:

```
// js/Cosmos.js
function Cosmos() {
    var self = this;
    this.background = new Background();

    // Fire game loop
    this.ticker = setInterval(function () {
        self.tick();
    }, 1000 / 60);
}
```

By using the `self` variable, the inner function gets to access `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in function scope for `setInterval` is `window`, but you can change function scope via `.bind` (or just redeclare `this` like the other answer says):

```
this.ticker = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000 / 60);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/SwQ5V/

Comment: bind is nice, but i think it's important to point out that it is not supported in older browsers (for example, IE8, or Safari Mobile: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'd usually suggest reassigning `this` because it gives you more flexibility too, but you already answered that first